# How do I attach objects from different sets

Tags: java

I have the following 2 sets in my driver class.  How do I attach a student to a module? For example, I need jane on module ufce1 and ufce2 and alex on ufce2 only.

```
Student jane = new Student("jane");
Student alex = new Student("alex");

Set<Student> students = new HashSet<Object>();
students.add(jane);
students.add(alex);

Module ufce1 = new Module("UFCE1");
Module ufce2 = new Module("UFCE2");

Set<Module> modules = new HashSet<Object>();
modules.add(ufce1);
modules.add(ufce2);
```

Modules class:

```
public class Module {
    private String name;

    public Module(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name; 
    }
}
```

Student Class:

```
public class Student {
    private String name;


    public Student(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

I tried using arrayLists but these result in duplication i.e. if a user tries adding a student onto a module they are already enrolled onto.

```
    Module m1 = new Module("m1", "Java");
    Module m2 = new Module("m2", "Software Design");
    Module m3 = new Module("m3", "PHP");
    Module m4 = new Module("m4", "MySQL");
    Module m5 = new Module("m5", "XML");

    ArrayList<Module> modules = new ArrayList<Module>();
    modules.add(m5);
    modules.add(m4);
    modules.add(m3);
    modules.add(m2);
    modules.add(m1);

    jane.addModule(m1);
    jane.addModule(m3);
    alex.addModule(m1);
    alex.addModule(m2);

    m1.addStudent(jane);
    m3.addStudent(jane);
    m1.addStudent(alex);
    m2.addStudent(alex);
```

Comment: What is `Module`? Is it a class you wrote yourself? This question is unanswerable because we don't know what's in class `Module` and class `Student`, and we don't know how these classes are supposed to be used.

Comment: Why don't you use `Set<Student>` instead of `Set<Object>`?

Comment: What does it mean to "attach a student to a module"?

Comment: I tried using arrayLists which worked fine until I wanted to attach a student to a module where it was possible to attach a student onto a module twice. Long story cut short, I've started from the beginning and I'm finding sets very difficult to understand using the Java API and can't find any examples of the internet attaching objects from different sets together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume Module is a class written by you.

if so you can have an Set in the Module class and also add addStudent() method in it.

```
public class Module{
    private Set<Student> students = new HashSet<Student>();
    public void addStudent(Student student){
          students.add(student);
    }

}
```